# Why is my Python C Extension leaking memory?

Tags: python, c, refcounting

The function below takes a python file handle, reads in packed binary data from the file, creates a Python dictionary and returns it.  If I loop it endlessly, it'll continually consume RAM.  What's wrong with my RefCounting?

```
static PyObject* __binParse_getDBHeader(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){

PyObject *o; //generic object
PyObject* pyDB = NULL; //this has to be a py file object

if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &pyDB)){
    return NULL;
} else {
    Py_INCREF(pyDB);
    if (!PyFile_Check(pyDB)){
        Py_DECREF(pyDB);
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IOError, "argument 1 must be open file handle");
        return NULL;
    }
}

FILE *fhDB = PyFile_AsFile(pyDB);

long offset = 0;
DB_HEADER *pdbHeader = malloc(sizeof(DB_HEADER));
fseek(fhDB,offset,SEEK_SET); //at the beginning
fread(pdbHeader, 1, sizeof(DB_HEADER), fhDB );
if (ferror(fhDB)){
    fclose(fhDB);
    Py_DECREF(pyDB);
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IOError, "failed reading database header");
    return NULL;
}
Py_DECREF(pyDB);

PyObject *pyDBHeader = PyDict_New();
Py_INCREF(pyDBHeader);

o=PyInt_FromLong(pdbHeader->version_number);
PyDict_SetItemString(pyDBHeader, "version", o);
Py_DECREF(o);

PyObject *pyTimeList = PyList_New(0);
Py_INCREF(pyTimeList);

int i;
for (i=0; i<NUM_DRAWERS; i++){
    //epochs
    o=PyInt_FromLong(pdbHeader->last_good_test[i]);
    PyList_Append(pyTimeList, o);
    Py_DECREF(o);
}
PyDict_SetItemString(pyDBHeader, "lastTest", pyTimeList);
Py_DECREF(pyTimeList);

o=PyInt_FromLong(pdbHeader->temp);
PyDict_SetItemString(pyDBHeader, "temp", o);
Py_DECREF(o);

free(pdbHeader);
return (pyDBHeader);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`PyDict_New()` returns a new reference, check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/c-api/dict.html) for `PyDict`. So if you increase the refcount immediately after creating it, you have two references to it. One is transferred to the caller when you return it as a result value, but the other one never goes aways.

You also don't need to incref `pyTimeList`. It's yours when you create it. However, you need to decref it, but you only decref it once, so it's leaked as well.

You also don't need to call `Py_INCREF` on `pyDB`. It's a borrowed reference and it won't go away as long as your function does not return, because it's still referenced in a lower stack frame.

Only if you want to keep the reference in another structure somewhere, you need to increse the refcount.

Cf. the [API docs](http://docs.python.org/c-api/arg.html)

Comment: Torsten, thanks, I just learned more in your 4 paragraphs, then I did staring at the docs all morning.  I'll check all my borrowed vs return new references.

Answer (score 5):

OT: Using successive calls to `PyList_Append` is a performance issue. Since you know how many results you'll get in advance, you can use:

```
PyObject *pyTimeList = PyList_New(NUM_DRAWERS);
int i;
for (i=0; i<NUM_DRAWERS; i++){
    o = PyInt_FromLong(pdbHeader->last_good_test[i]);
    PyList_SET_ITEM(pyTimeList, i, o);
}
```

Observe that you may not decrease the refcount of `o` after calling `PyList_SET_ITEM`, because it "steals" a reference. Check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/c-api/list.html).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Python-C. However, My experience with COM reference counting says that a newly created reference-counted object has a reference count of **1**. So your Py_INCREF(pyDB) after PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &pyDB) and PyObject *pyDBHeader = PyDict_New(); are the culprit. Their reference counts are already 2.